# Unexpected token ILLEGAL for jquery script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple code which creates a popup and add a text, which is working fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script src='./js/jquery.min.js'></script><script>var blade = window.open("", "BLADE", "width=500, height=500, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");$(blade.document.body).html("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>this is my 'content'</body></html>");</script></body></html>
```

the issue is when I add into child (new html) a line to load jquery as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script src='./js/jquery.min.js'></script><script>var blade = window.open("", "BLADE", "width=500, height=500, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");$(blade.document.body).html("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script src='./js/jquery.min.js'></script>this is my 'content'</body></html>");</script></body></html>
```

then popup is not created and on main-page I can see: `this is my 'content'");`
When checking js console I can see in this instance also: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I would be grateful for helping me out how to add jquery to pop-up html window code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your end script tag, like below:

```
$(blade.document.body).html("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script src='./js/jquery.min.js'><\/script>this is my 'content'</body></html>");
```

`</script>` to `<\/script>`

Also, you don't need `"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>"` in your append as it's pointless since your target node is `body` already!

Answer (score 2):

It is the classic case of the `</script>` inside the string closing the outside script block.

```
></scr" + "ipt>th
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<body>
  <script src='./js/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    var blade = window.open("", "BLADE", "width=500, height=500, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");
    $(blade.document.body).html("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script src='./js/jquery.min.js'></sc" + "ript>this is my 'content'</body></html>");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Man that's old school.  I haven't done that since document.write()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the link to your JS file might not be working. There shouldn't be a './' unless your 'js' folder is within a folder called '.', which I doubt.

Double check that you're linking to the correct file, maybe even try linking to a hosted version of it (below) just to be sure that's the problem.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```